# Converting PuTTY's svn repository to mercurial repository

Tags: svn, mercurial, dvcs, putty

I'm going to manage a Korean localized version of PuTTY in mercurial.

The requirements for the mercurial repository:

- We should be able to keep track of the latest revisions from the PuTTY svn repository.
- No pushing is required.

My plan is to have the original trunk and branches as named branches in the mercurial repository, and to add my own branch.
I'm going to use *hgsubversion* for continuous pulling after initial conversion.

The problem is, the PuTTY repository (http://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/) is **not** in the standard layout, and more worse, contains other projects also. DVCS conversion tools work well with standard layout repositories, but not with non-standard ones.

So I have to map the directories to make it "standard" like:

- `/putty` => `/trunk`
- `/putty-0.xx` => `/tags/0.xx`
- `/putty-branch-0.xx` => `/branches/0.xx`
- ignore all other directories

If the trunk has every revisions required for the releases, converting only the trunk would be okay.
But unfortunately, the version 0.62 is released at the putty-branch-0.61 branch! So I could not get the latest revisions for it. :(

I'm trying to use `svnsync`, `svnadmin dump` and `svndumpfilter` to convert the original svn repository standard before mercurial conversion, but manual mapping the directories as I want is not possible with them. (Or maybe I don't know how to do it with them.)

Any suggestions and comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the repository. You are correct that `svndumpfilter` cannot be used to rename a file throughout the history, so I wrote a small script that does the renaming in the dump file. The only tricky part was to add the creation of the `tags` and `branches` folder. To use the script, you should make a cronjob or similar that:

1. downloads the [latest Putty SVN dump file](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/putty-svn.dump.gz):

   ```
   $ wget http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/putty-svn.dump.gz
   ```
2. fixes the dump file with the script:

   ```
   $ zcat putty-svn.dump.gz | fix-dump.py > fixed.dump
   ```
3. loads it into a new empty repository:

   ```
   $ svnadmin create putty
   $ svnadmin load putty < fixed.dump
   ```
4. converts the Subversion repository into a Mercurial repository:

   $ hg convert file://$PWD/putty

As far as I can see, the branches and tags are created correctly.

You ask for **continuous pulling** (incremental conversion). Luckily, both `hg convert` and `hgsubversion` support this. You'll need to redo steps 1–3 every day before you can convert the changesets into Mercurial. This will work since the first three steps are *deterministic*. That means that your `putty` SVN repository behaves as if the Putty developers worked directly in it using the proper branch and tag names you maintain there.

The script is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, re

moves = [(r"^Node(-copyfrom|)?-path: %s" % pattern, r"Node\1-path: %s" % repl)
         for (pattern, repl) in [(r"putty-branch-(0\...)", r"branches/\2"),
                                 (r"putty-(0\...)", r"tags/\2"),
                                 (r"putty(/|\n)", r"trunk\2")]]

empty_dir_template = """\
Node-path: %s
Node-kind: dir
Node-action: add
Prop-content-length: 10
Content-length: 10

PROPS-END\n\n"""

created_dirs = False
for line in sys.stdin:
    if not created_dirs and line == "Node-path: putty\n":
        sys.stdout.write(empty_dir_template % "tags")
        sys.stdout.write(empty_dir_template % "branches")
        created_dirs = True
    for pattern, repl in moves:
        line, count = re.subn(pattern, repl, line, 1)
        if count > 0: break
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to keep track of ONLY the released source code, not every revision.

So the result is here: https://bitbucket.org/daybreaker/iputty/changesets .

To do this, I have followed these steps (for example):

```
svn ls -R svn://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/putty-0.58 > 58.txt
svn ls -R svn://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/putty-0.59 > 59.txt
svn ls -R svn://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/putty-0.60 > 60.txt
svn ls -R svn://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/putty-0.61 > 61.txt
svn ls -R svn://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/putty-0.62 > 62.txt

hg init iputty
cd iputty
svn export --force svn://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/putty-0.58 .
hg branch original
hg add
hg commit -m 'Imported PuTTY 0.58 release.'
svn export --force svn://svn.tartarus.org/sgt/putty-0.59 .
diff -U3 ../58.txt ../59.txt
hg add (added files from diff)
hg rm (removed files from diff)
hg commit -m 'Imported PuTTY 0.59 release.'
(repeat this for the remaining releases)

hg up -r(rev# of 0.60 release)
svn export --force (URL of my own modified PuTTY repository) .
hg branch default
hg commit -m 'Imported the most recent dPuTTY source code. blah blah'
```